# EF6 with one database per client (same context)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, connection-string, entity-framework-6, database-migration, dbcontext

I am developping an ASP.Net MVC 5 application that will be a SaaS for my clients. I want to use EF6 and I am currently using localDb. I am an Entity Framwork beginner and I am having a hard time learning it. I have been searching the web for the last 2 days, found different approaches but never found something clear for me that would answers my questions.

I followed Scott Allen Tutorial on ASP.Net MVC 4 and 5 so currently, I have 2 contexts, 'IdendityDbContext' and 'MyAppDbContext' both pointing to the DefaultConnection sting using a database called MyAppDb.mdf

I want my customers to be able to login on the website and connect to their own database so I was planning on creating a new ConnectionString (and database) for each of my clients and keeping one ConnectionString for my client Accounts information using my IdendityDbContext.

I have plenty of questions but here the 2 most importants ones :

1) I am not sure how to do that and test it locally. Do I have to create new data connections for all my clients and when a client connect, I edit the connection string dynamically and pass it to 'MyAppContext' ?

2) Even if I am able to do this, let's say I have 200 customers, it means I will have 201 databases : 1 Account Database (IdentityDbContext) and 200 Client Databases (MyAppDbContext). If I change my model in the future, does it means I have to run package manager console migrations command line for each of the 200 databases ? This seems brutal. There must be a way to propagate my model easily on every clients database right?

Sorry for the long post and thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please ask one question a time. The two issues are very different.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to (1) is basically "yes", you need to do just that. The answer to (2) is that you'll have to run migrations against all the databases. I can't imagine how you would think there would be any other way to do it, you've got 200 separate databases that all need the same schema change. The only way to accomplish that is to run the same script (or migration) against each one of them. That's the downside of a single-tenant model like you've got.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. So you suggest I should have 1 database for my clients ? I have search for that as well but I didn't understand how I could achieve that.

Comment: I'm not suggesting one way or the other. Only you, and your requirements, can decide whether you should be single- or multi-tenant. There is never one perfect solution, there are always trade-offs. Search for those terms and do some reading on the trade-offs and then decide.

Answer (score 0):

A few things you should know since you're new to all of this. First, LocalDB is only for development. It's fine to use it while in development, but remember that you'll need a full SQL Server instance when it comes time to deploy. It's surprising how common a hangup this is, so I just want make sure you know out the gate.

Second, migrations, at least code-first migrations, are *also* for development. You should never run your code-first migrations against a production database. Not only would this require that you actually access the production database directly from Visual Studio, which is a pretty big no-no in and of itself, but nothing should ever happen on a production database unless you explicitly know what's changing, where. I have a [write-up about how to migrate production databases](http://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/) that might be worth looking at.

For something like your 200 database scenario, though, it would probably be better to invest in something like this from [Red Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/).